# Was just sent a JS virus. How do I safely display the output?

Tags: javascript, unicode, virus

I just received a virus that looks something like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
var s="=nfub!iuuq.frvjw>#sfgsfti#!------REST OF PAYLOAD REMOVED-----?";
m=""; 
for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) 
{   
if(s.charCodeAt(i) == 28)
{     
m+= '&';
}
 else if 
(s.charCodeAt(i) == 23) 
{     m+= '!';} 
else 
{     
 m+=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)-1); 
}}
document.write(m);//-->
</script>
```

I'm not a JS expert but I would like to decrypt the contents of that string.  Can you tell me the best way to alter document.write to see what it's doing?

Comment: It's a very simple substitution cypher, B->A, etc. You can read it by hand if you squint at it enough. "meta!http.equiv>#refrefh#...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a `<textarea id="foo"></textarea>`,  and write

```
document.getElementsById('foo').value = m;
```

---

Alternatively, you could encode `<` and `&` to `&lt;` and `&amp;` and keep the `document.write`.

---

FYI, the payload starts with

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
```

so looks like it just redirects the user into the a malicious site.

Comment: @KennyTM - sorry I deleted my n00b question-in-comments.  It makes sense now

Comment: Yes, the alert did say it was redirecting me to a malicious website.  Thanks!

Comment: Alert? Kenny wasn't at all suggesting to use an alert.

Comment: @BalusC: Pretty sure he means that when his computer executed the code, his browser's malware detection kicked in and warned him that he was going to a dangerous site.

Comment: @chuck @BaluscActually I used an alert as the solution, and then tried the DIV code too.  I'll try every bit of stack-homework if it means I learn something

Answer (score 2):

Use Malzilla to decode the URL.
http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 Seems like a neat, usefull and complicated at the same time.  I got it to work on a site I trust. Not sure what all the buttons do though or when I need em.

Answer (score 1):

Since `m` is a String, you can just replace `document.write()` by `alert()`. [Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGqYu/).

It seem to be creating a meta refresh header, probably with intent to inject it in the head of the current HTML page in order to redirect to a different (malicious?) page.

Comment: That is what I thought, but just wanted to be sure.  I don't want to get infected...

Answer (score 1):

Don't run it your browser, instead try running it in FireBug for example (except `document.write(m)` line - just use FireBug to see contents of m variable).

Most of these embed an iframe into your site